# TextEditingController throws null when used .text getter/setter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, when I assign a value to a TextField or check that TextField widget's values using the TextEditingController, I get a NoMethodError which says The getter/setter "text" was called on a null.

I've tried the Widget test with this code:

```
class TestTEC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestTECstate createState() => TestTECstate();
}

class TestTECstate extends State<TestTEC> {
  var textController = new TextEditingController();
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(controller: textController),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              textController.text = "New text";
            });
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the test code I used:

```
 testWidgets('smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget((TestTEC()));
    await tester.tap(find.byType(RaisedButton));
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.text('New text'), findsOneWidget);
    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), 'I am a text');
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.text('I am a test'), findsOneWidget);
    await tester.tap(find.byType(RaisedButton));
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.text('New text'), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

This was the output:

```
 NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'text=' was called on null.
  Receiver: null
  Tried calling: text="key"
  dart:core               Object.noSuchMethod
  widget_test.dart 91:11  textEditingControllerTest
  widget_test.dart 75:14  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

I've tried deleting and reinstalling flutter sdk. 
The same problem is happening my another computer.

I've used the .text property before, this problem didn't happen before version 1.5.4.hotfix2 to me. If I'm doing something wrong then please correct me. I can't even check whether the TextField is empty or not by controller.text.isEmpty, it also throws the "text" was called on null.